# Imputing missing values keeping a rectangular shape in mind

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a data set where number denotes a particular color. Since i have large data set, i am sharing a sample data and work. I am looking forward to create this

**Output**

```
d <- matrix(c(
     1, 1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  1,
1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  1,
1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  1,
1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  1,
1,  2,  3,  3,  2,  1,
1,  2,  2,  2,  2,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1), nrow=13, byrow = TRUE)
```

from this **Input** :

```
d_mi <- d
d_mi[ sample(1:length(d), length(d)*0.3) ] <- NA
d_mi
```

Optional : Output(in color mode)
[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What is the logic for why row 5 should go back to 3's? I see no logical reason why they couldn't be 2's as well? You can't go back to something that you've destructively changed.

Comment: There is a pattern that there would/could be rectangle under rectangle.